# Error when creating PDF from ASP.NET report

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I'm trying to programmatically create a pdf file from ASP.NET report. When I run the program it throws the following error:

> Error occurred during report processing. Loading this assembly would
>   produce a different grant set from other instances. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131401)

I already tried adding

```xml
<trust level="Full">
```

to my applications web.config and reset the IIS.

Any other ideas?

Comment: You need to add more details. Describe how you're creating the PDF.

Comment: Make sure that you build the PDF in memory, and not on a local drive.  Need to see some code.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling ReportViewer 2005 SP2 and then IIS reset solved my problem.